# inter process communication in opengl

Tags: opengl

I have a process A that starts OpenGL programm with empty world, and need to populate this world from process B that start as separated programm, also all events (like raycast, etc ) has to be communicated from process A to B.

Could someone at least point me in right direction ?

PS 
Is this something to do with OpenGL context ?

Comment: IPC is an OS feature and will depend on which system you're on and the language you're coding in; nothing to do with OpenGL or rendering API.

Comment: This seems nothing to do with OpenGL but more like a simple client/server communication setup. Maybe you need to talk a little about what you're *actually* trying to do rather than how you're trying to do it?

Comment: I am trying to build up the container that will load separate modules. As an example we can think of Chrome browser as a container and each tab is kind of module, that   work inside this container. Do you know what might be best solution here in case I am trying to use OpenGL ?

Comment: Again, this question has nothing to do with OpenGL. OpenGL is how you'll use the received data to draw something. That's an entirely separate problem from how you receive that data in the first place. Presumably you researched inter-process communication and [looked for existing Q&A about it](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=inter-process) as a starting point. How did you try implementing this based on what you've learned so far, and where are you stuck?